# C#, 3.0, how to associate unknown number of values with an object

Tags: c#

I am new to C#, using C# 3.0
Need to create unknown number of objects (no more than 50)
My thinking is to store them in an ArrayList so that I don't have to name them but can still access them when required..
These objects will have a few known properties but they will need to have a number of other values associated with them. This number is unknown but is low, less than 20-30 let's say.
Not sure how to handle the unknown values. Is it possible I can store them in an array associated with each object? But how do I refer to them?
Or can this be done with interfaces?
I read about dynamic properties but it doesn't seem is supported in 3.0.

Thanks!
-gg2

Comment: I'm not sure I got it. You either need  [dynamic or **Reflection**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/593881/What-is-the-difference-between)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this quite often in the field that I work in. Typically I create an object that holds the known values, and then an indexing property to hold the unknown values. The object looks something like this:

```
public class KindOfUnknown
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _metadata = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    public object KnownValue1 { get; set; }
    public object KnownValue2 { get; set; }
    public object KnownValue3 { get; set; }
    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get { return _metadata[propertyName]; }
        set
        {
            _metadata[propertyName] = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ContainsProperty(string propertyName)
    {
        return _metadata.ContainsKey(propertyName);
    }

}
```

There are 3 known properties here, `KnownValue1`, `KnownValue2`, and `KnownValue3`. You can replace them with meaningful names and concrete types/add or subtract more properties as needed.

Then there is an indexer property that allows you to set/get unknown values that are stored in a `Dictionary<string, object>`. You would call it like this:

```
var myObject = new KindOfUnknown();
myObject["MyCustomProperty"] = "Some value here"; //Does not have to be a string
myObject.KnownValue1 = SOME_VALUE;
```

The only draw-back here is that you need to know what you are storing in the custom property. The types will be boxed and can have some performance issues but I've found it works relatively well.

`dynamic` won't work because as you've found, it doesn't exist in C#3, and even if it did its not the right thing to use. The closest you can get in C#4 is deriving a type from `DynamicObject` that allows you to create properties of the type "on the fly". `dynamic` just defers checking that the object on the right side of the "." exists until runtime (ostensibly), it doesn't allow you to construct the type dynamically.

So, in order to create your set of an unknown number of items, you should use a `List<T>`, not `ArrayList`, which is effectively depreciated since generics were introduced. To use it, create a new one:

`List<KindOfUnknown> myObjects = new List<KindOfUnknown>();`

Then you can add to them like:

`myObjects.Add(new KindOfUnknown() { KnownValue1 = ... });`

And you can also use indexers and for-each loops as you see fit just like any other array. The advantage of using a `List<T>` over an `ArrayList` is that the objects are not boxed in memory.

Comment: Ron, thanks very much for this!

Yes, I meant to say I plan to use List<T> that is part of the Generics.
I am taking a better look at your suggestion.

From your post:

myObject["MyCustomProperty"] = "Some value here";

That suggests I need to come up with a name ("MyCustomProperty") for all these uknown values and I'd rather not do that.
I guess a workaround would be to create my own indexer (incrementing numbers) and use that for "MyCustomProperty"?

Thanks again for your time, much appreciated!

Comment: You could always just use a `List<object>` and include an `Add` method in the class, then change the text indexer in the class out for an integer index.

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping a dictionary on each object that links to the unknown properties you may need.

Comment: Tnanks Barett. I think you are suggesting the same think Ron Beyer suggested.

Comment: Correct! (I beat him to the punch, but his answer with code examples is clearly superior!)